# Same code works diffferently regarding file size

Tags: python

I am running a simple code to select text from lines in the input file and write that text to an output file.

```
with open('inputpath', 'r') as vh_datoteka, open('outputpath', 'w') as iz_datoteka:
        for line in vh_datoteka:
            NMEA = str(line) [24:-39]
            iz_datoteka.write (NMEA + '\n')
```

The data I need to process looks something like this (two lines):

```
2012-05-01
23:59:59.007;!AIVDM,1,1,0,,33cm>k100013vglDPkW1QSin0000,0*6E;2470028;1;NULL;2012-05-01
21:59:59.007 2012-05-01
23:59:59.007;!AIVDM,1,1,0,,19NSBn001nQ8<7vDhIq43C<2280F,0*07;2470032;1;NULL;2012-05-01
21:59:59.007 ...
```

Since I have large files to process (~2GB) I first tested the code on a small part of one of the large files (simply copied first 1000 or so lines and saved them into a test file).

The code worked perfectly and I got the results I was looking for:

```
&#33;AIVDM,1,1,0,,33cm>k100013vglDPkW1QSin0000,0*6E;
!AIVDM,1,1,0,,19NSBn001nQ8<7vDhIq43C<2280F,0*07;
```

After that I tried using the code on the whole data and got very different outputs:

```
2 3 : 5 9 : 5 9 . 0 0 7 ; ! A I V D M , 1 , 1 , 0 , , 3 3 c m > k 1 0
0 0 1 3 v g l D P k W 1 Q S i n 0 0 0 0 , 0 * 6 E ; 2 4 7 0 0 2 8 ; 1
; N U L L ; 2 0 1 2 -   3 : 5 9 : 5 9 . 0 0 7 ; ! A I V D M , 1 , 1 ,
0 , , 1 9 N S B n 0 0 1 n Q 8 < 7 v D h I q 4 3 C < 2 2 8 0 F , 0 * 0
7 ; 2 4 7 0 0 3 2 ; 1 ; N U L L ; 2 0 1 2 - ...
```

I have been trying to figure out the reason for such behaviour and have ran out of ideas and obviously need help.

Comment: Does your small sample file have the same encoding as the larger original file?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Tobias for your comment.

Apparently the large data files were in UTF16-LE, which was the problem. I corrected the python code to read in utf16 and write to utf8 and that did the trick.

```
with codecs.open('inputpath', 'r', encoding='utf-16-le') as vh_datoteka, open('outputpath', 'w') as iz_datoteka:
        for line in vh_datoteka:
            NMEA = str(line) [24:-39]
            iz_line = NMEA + '\n'
            iz_datoteka.write (iz_line.encode('utf-8'))
```